# Table's border-radius does not function as expected

Tags: html, css, html-table

I want to add a border radius around the entire table. But the following code is not working in both the latest versions of Firefox and Google Chrome.

```css
table {
  border-spacing: 0;
  width: 600px;
  margin: 30px;
  border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
  border-radius: 6px 6px 6px 6px;
  -moz-border-radius: 6px 6px 6px 6px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 6px 6px 6px 6px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px #CCCCCC;
}

table th:first-child {
  border-radius: 6px 0 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 6px 0 0 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 6px 0 0 0;
}

table th:last-child {
  border-radius: 0 6px 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 6px 0 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 6px 0 0;
}

table td:first-child,
.bordered th:first-child {
  border-left: medium none;
}

table th {
  background-color: #DCE9F9;
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(center top, #F8F8F8, #ECECEC);
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 bottom, from(#F8F8F8), to(#ECECEC), color-stop(.4, #F8F8F8));
  border-top: medium none;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8) inset;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}

table td,
table th {
  border-left: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
  border-top: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<table class="bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th><label>Labels</label></th>
      <th><label>Labels</label></th>
      <th><label>Labels</label></th>
      <th><label>Labels</label></th>
      <th><label>Labels</label></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><label>Value</label></td>
      <td><label>Value</label></td>
      <td><label>Value</label></td>
      <td><label>Value</label></td>
      <td><label>Value</label></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XvdX9/521/)

Answer (score 57, accepted):

It works, this is a problem with the tool used: **normalized CSS** by jsFiddle is causing the problem by hiding you the default of browsers...
See http://jsfiddle.net/XvdX9/5/

**EDIT:**
[normalize.css](http://fiddle.jshell.net/css/normalize.css) stylesheet from jsFiddle adds the instruction `border-collapse: collapse` to all tables and it renders them completely differently in CSS2.1:

- [The separated borders model](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html#separated-borders)
- [The collapsing border model](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html#collapsing-borders)

Differences between the 2 models can be seen in this other fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/XvdX9/11/ (with some transparencies on cells and an enormous border-radius on the top-left one, in order to see what happens on table vs its cells)

In the same CSS2.1 page about HTML tables, there are also explanations about what browsers should/could do with empty-cells in the separated borders model, the difference between `border-style: none` and `border-style: hidden` in the collapsing borders model, how width is calculated and which border should display if both table, row and cell elements define 3 different styles on the same border.

Comment: Can you explain why normalize causes this problem? When I inspect the elements the fiddle, I can't find anything that would kill the border-radius.

Comment: Thanks. I also found the following solution. :)

Comment: @Fresheyeball I added links to documentation and a comparison. I'm glad I learned directly CSS a few years ago and didn't work in the field back when table layout were (to be) used and abused along with `spacer.gif` ;)

Comment: `overflow` should be set to `hidden` if you want `border-radius` to affect the content

Comment: @dudelgrincen It'll "cut" rectangular backgrounds on cells, similar to a mask, good idea if you're sure nothing ever will have to display outside a table (simpler than border-radius on 4 corner cells). But I often have tooltips or even, in complex tables, dropdowns (filters, etc)

Comment: @BorisD.Teoharov this should be included in the answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 144):

`border-collapse: separate !important;` worked.

Thanks.

**HTML**

```
<table class="bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th><label>Labels</label></th>
            <th><label>Labels</label></th>
            <th><label>Labels</label></th>
            <th><label>Labels</label></th>
            <th><label>Labels</label></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><label>Value</label></td>
            <td><label>Value</label></td>
            <td><label>Value</label></td>
            <td><label>Value</label></td>
            <td><label>Value</label></td>                            
        </tr>
    </tbody>                    
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
table {
    border-collapse: separate !important;
    border-spacing: 0;
    width: 600px;
    margin: 30px;
}
.bordered {
    border: solid #ccc 1px;
    -moz-border-radius: 6px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px #ccc;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px #ccc;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px #ccc;
}
.bordered tr:hover {
    background: #ECECEC;    
    -webkit-transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out;
}
.bordered td, .bordered th {
    border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: left;
}
.bordered th {
    background-color: #ECECEC;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#F8F8F8), to(#ECECEC));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #F8F8F8, #ECECEC);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #F8F8F8, #ECECEC);    
    background-image: linear-gradient(top, #F8F8F8, #ECECEC);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.8) inset;
    -moz-box-shadow:0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.8) inset;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.8) inset;
    border-top: none;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.5);
}
.bordered td:first-child, .bordered th:first-child {
    border-left: none;
}
.bordered th:first-child {
    -moz-border-radius: 6px 0 0 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px 0 0 0;
    border-radius: 6px 0 0 0;
}
.bordered th:last-child {
    -moz-border-radius: 0 6px 0 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 6px 0 0;
    border-radius: 0 6px 0 0;
}
.bordered th:only-child{
    -moz-border-radius: 6px 6px 0 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px 6px 0 0;
    border-radius: 6px 6px 0 0;
}
.bordered tr:last-child td:first-child {
    -moz-border-radius: 0 0 0 6px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 0 6px;
    border-radius: 0 0 0 6px;
}
.bordered tr:last-child td:last-child {
    -moz-border-radius: 0 0 6px 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 6px 0;
    border-radius: 0 0 6px 0;
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tapas_23571113/XvdX9/10/)

Comment: border-collapse: separate !important;  Yeah worked for me too.

Answer (score 35):

This is my solution using the wrapper, just removing `border-collapse` might not be helpful always, because you might want to have borders.

```css
.wrapper {
  overflow: auto;
  border-radius: 6px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

table {
  border-spacing: 0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-style: hidden;

  width:100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}

th, td {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Column 1</th>
        <th>Column 2</th>
        <th>Column 3</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Foo Bar boo</td>
        <td>Lipsum</td>
        <td>Beehuum Doh</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Dolor sit</td>
        <td>ahmad</td>
        <td>Polymorphism</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Kerbalium</td>
        <td>Caton, gookame kyak</td>
        <td>Corona Premium Beer</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>  
</div>
```

This article helped: https://css-tricks.com/table-borders-inside/

Comment: I had to add `border-radius: 6px;` to both the DIV and the TABLE since I did not want to use `overflow: auto` style on the DIV for some other reasons. Using `border-radius` on both TABLE and DIV makes `overflow: auto` unnecessary.

Comment: This is the best solution here, worked perfectly for me.

Answer (score 13):

Just add `overflow:hidden` to the table with `border-radius`.

```css
.tablewithradius {
  overflow:hidden ;
  border-radius: 15px;
}
```

Comment: This works, but adds a visual bug on the corners for me, where the borders are overflowing

Answer (score 9):

A note to this old question:

My *reset.css* had set `border-spacing: 0`, causing the corners to get cut off. I had to set it to `3px` for my radius to work properly (value will depend on the radius in question).

Answer (score 7):

```
<div class="leads-search-table">
                    <div class="row col-md-6 col-md-offset-2 custyle">
                    <table class="table custab bordered">
                    <thead>

                        <tr>
                            <th>ID</th>
                            <th>Title</th>
                            <th>Parent ID</th>
                            <th class="text-center">Action</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                            <tr>
                                <td>1</td>
                                <td>News</td>
                                <td>News Cate</td>
                                <td class="text-center"><a class='btn btn-info btn-xs' href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span> Edit</a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> Del</a></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>2</td>
                                <td>Products</td>
                                <td>Main Products</td>
                                <td class="text-center"><a class='btn btn-info btn-xs' href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span> Edit</a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> Del</a></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>3</td>
                                <td>Blogs</td>
                                <td>Parent Blogs</td>
                                <td class="text-center"><a class='btn btn-info btn-xs' href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span> Edit</a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> Del</a></td>
                            </tr>
                    </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Css

```
.custab{
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    margin: 5% 0;
    transition: 0.5s;
    background-color: #fff;
    -webkit-border-radius:4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border-collapse: separate;
}
```

Comment: There is CSS for the DIV missing in this answer.

Answer (score 4):

No need to worry..Just add
overflow: hidden;
and then apply border radius. Border radius will be applied to all the four sides.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please take the time to absorb SO's [recommendations addressed to new users](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You may take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour); then do read what's [on-topic here] (https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Thanks for answer. But I am sorta clueless in CSS. I know the basics. But IDK why we should apply `overflow: "hidden"`. Can you say why?

Answer (score 2):

To use border radius I have a border radius of 20px in the table, and then put the border radius on the first child of the table header (th) and the last child of the table header.

```
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-radius:20px;
  padding: 10px;
}

table th:first-child {
  /* border-radius = top left, top right, bottom right, bottom left */
    border-radius: 20px 0 0 0; /* curves the top left */
    padding-left: 15px;
}

table th:last-child {
    border-radius: 0 20px 0 0; /* curves the top right */
}
```

This however will not work if this is done with table data (td) because it will add a curve onto each table row. This is not a problem if you only have 2 rows in your table but any additional ones will add curves onto the inner rows too.
You only want these curves on the outside of the table.
So for this, add an id to your last row.
Then you can apply the curves to them.

```
/* curves the first tableData in the last row */

#lastRow td:first-child {
    border-radius: 0 0 0 20px; /* bottom left curve */
}

/* curves the last tableData in the last row */

#lastRow td:last-child {
    border-radius: 0 0 20px 0; /* bottom right curve */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply add this:

```css
table {
   border-radius: 8px;
   border-collapse: separate;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `display: inline-block;` or `display: block;`. The table uses the default property as `display: table;` that's why border-radius does not work as expected.

```css
table {
   border-radius: 8px;
   display: inline-block;
}
```