# Use round corners without gif and add background color on top and underneath instead of gif

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create an email template. 
For the bottom and top headers I wish to use round corners but the only way that I have managed to do this now is using gif files...How can I do this without on the code below ? 
(Right now the table border is incomplete up and down, not closed).
Also I have tried adding a gif image in the center

```
<td valign="top" align="center"><img src="file:///C|/Users/the/Desktop/my GIF.gif" width="288" height="146"></td>
```

And I would like to have background color around the edges or behind the image  considering that it is transparent - and also on the bottom.

Any other edits on this Template more than welcome.

```
<html><head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<base target="_blank">
<title>==</title>
</head><body>

<table width="614" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px;  color:#656565;">
    <tbody><tr>
        <td valign="top" align="center"><img src="file:///C|/Users/the/Desktop/my GIF.gif" width="288" height="146"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td valign="top" style="border-left:1px solid #cbd6dc;border-right:1px solid #cbd6dc; padding:0 18px 20px; text-align:left;">
              <table width="576" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px;">
                <tbody><tr>
                    <td valign="top" style="font-size:14px; padding:10px 0 15px;  font-weight:bold">Hello user,<br></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                   <td valign="top" style="font-size:19px; padding:10px 0 16px 0; text-align:center;color:#449AC2; ">Congragulations ! </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                   <td valign="top" style=" padding:0 0 15px;"> 
                        <table style="width:554px; border:#d3dde2 1px solid; background:#eef3f6;" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                <tbody><tr>
                                    <td valign="top"><div style="font-size:12px; padding:16px  25px 0 0; line-height:20px;  text-align:left;padding-bottom:20px;"><a href="http://www.website.com/signup?sname=zmail23&amp;ISP=gmail&amp;invitation_key=201307f998225213537deb9e8a3c5930&amp;tt=773&amp;sub=755&amp;referral=bacorichard&amp;tp=8&amp;hr=2013072111&amp;cid=23&amp;source=5" style=" color:#666; text-decoration:none">.    
                                        <p>Congragulations my text here <br>
    <br>                                        
                                  </p></a></div><a href="http://www.website.com/signup?sname=zmail23&amp;ISP=gmail&amp;invitation_key=201307f998225213537deb9e8a3c5930&amp;tt=773&amp;sub=755&amp;referral=bacorichard&amp;tp=8&amp;hr=2013072111&amp;cid=23&amp;source=5" style=" color:#666; text-decoration:none"></a></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td valign="bottom" style="padding:0 0 50px 0"><a target="_blank" style=" border:2px solid #fff; padding:5px 6px; background:#f7b225; color:#ffffff; font-size: 16px; font-weight: bold; text-align: center;text-decoration:none; " href="http://www.website.com/signup?sname=zmail23&amp;ISP=gmail&amp;invitation_key=201307f998225213537deb9e8a3c5930&amp;tt=773&amp;sub=755&amp;referral=bacorichard&amp;tp=8&amp;hr=2013072111&amp;cid=23&amp;source=5"> Take me there</a></td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody></table> 
                   </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td valign="top" style="padding-bottom:18px;">
                        <div style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:14px; text-align:left; padding:0 ; margin:0;color:#656565">Regards,</div>
                         <div style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:14px; text-align:left; padding:0; margin:0;color:#656565">The Team</div>
                     </td>
                </tr>

             </tbody></table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td valign="top" style="font-size:11px; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; line-height:16px; padding:10px 0; background:#f6f7fa;border-left:1px solid #cbd6dc;border-right:1px solid #cbd6dc;border-top:1px solid #cbd6dc; padding:15px 18px 0 18px; text-align:center;">



           </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td valign="top"><img align="top" src="width=&quot;614&quot;" height="23"> </td>
    </tr>
</tbody></table> 
<img src="http://signup.website.com/signup/open_invitation/2013072111/773/755/23/8?isp=gmail&amp;source=5" style="display:none;visibility:hidden;" height="0" width="0/">


</body></html>
```

Comment: Considering you use an email client to view the mail, you do not know if they will support it. But if you want to try, you will likely need to layout your email with div tags and use "border-radius" in the CSS.

Comment: You may want to look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10666573/border-radius-of-table-is-not-working). There they have an example for a rounded table.

Answer (score 1):

You can add border-radius property to your table style.

```
style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px;border:1px solid #cbd6dc;border-radius: 5px;"
```

Answer (score 0):

To use rounded corners you can use CSS like this on most elements:

```
border-radius: 5px;
```

JSFiddle example:

**http://jsfiddle.net/CbfvQ/**

The higher the number the more rounded the corners become.

If you want inline style rather than CSS methods then add to the style like this:

```
style="border-radius:5px;border:1px solid #cbd6dc;"
```

Be sure to check the browser compatibility of this feature:

**http://caniuse.com/border-radius** it is widely supported now :)

Comment: @TobiasKienzler `I don't see what the problem is` :) Equally if you have an issue with that this is not the place to make the comment.

Comment: It _has_ already been discussed on meta, see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/135112/146482). I'm not eager to stalk everyone who didn't read it, but due to a lack of "review reviews" that's the only way to attempt improving this a bit - we shouldn't encourage new users to suggest these edits