# converted html table to div but cells and content don't line up

Tags: html, css

I was trying to make div table with round edges of top corners,  but divs of cells and table brow do not line up and text in description doesnt show up completely.

[image]

```
/*
Div table
*/

.rTable {
    width: 70%;
    font-family: verdana,arial,sans-serif;
    font-size:11px;
    color:#333333;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: #999999;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    }

.rTableHeading, .rTableFoot {
    clear: both;
    background-color:#c3dde0;
    }

.rTableBody {
    clear: both;
}

.rTableRow {
    clear: both;
    display:inline-block;
    overflow: no-scroll;
    background-color:#d4e3e5;
}

.rTableHead, .rTableFoot{
    background-color:#c3dde0;
    border-width: 0px;
    padding: 6px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #a9c6c9;      
    font-weight: bold;
    width:10%;
    } 

.rTableCell {
    background-color: transparent;
    width: 10%;
    border-width: 1px;
    padding: 5px;
    border-style: solid;
    opacity: 0.5;
    border-color: #a9c6c9;
}

.rTableDescCell {
    width:10%;
}

.rTableCell, .rTableHead {
    float: left;    
    height: 20px;       
    overflow: hidden; 
    padding: 1px 1.8%;      
    width: 10%; 
    }
```

this is displayed in html view as shown below:

```
        <div class="rTable">
        <div class="rTableHeading roundEdgeTop">
            <div class="rTableHead">
                Date
            </div>
            <div class="rTableHead">
                Min
            </div>
            <div class="rTableHead">
                Max
            </div>
            <div class="rTableHead">
                Humidity
            </div>
            <div class="rTableHead">
                Description
            </div>
            <div class="rTableHead">
                Sunrise
            </div>
            <div class="rTableHead">
                Sunset
            </div>                  
        </div>
        <div class="rTableBody">
        {% for day in forcast_list %}
            <div class="rTableRow" onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor='#ffff66';"onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor='#d4e3e5';" >
            {% for n in range(7) %}
                <div class="rTableCell">
                    {{day[n]}}
                </div>
            {% endfor %}            
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: floated elements don't behave as table row/cell. what are you trying to do?

Comment: Short answer is: **do not do the conversion**. This is one of the few legitimate cases where `<table>` should actually be used, instead of `<div>`s. [`<table>` elements do support border-radius](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10666573/border-radius-of-table-is-not-working). You are presenting tabulated data, so use the correct tag designed specifically for the purpose. If you're adamant about using `<div>`, look into `display: table`.

Comment: removing `float: left;` messes up things big time.

Comment: yea make sense, I will keep the html table tag however I do not know why it is pushed to make use of div based tables instead of html table.